# How to enable notification on applewatch?

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-push-notifications, apple-watch

I can get push notifications on an Iphone device, but I cannot get them on apple watch,please advise.
On simulator notification test works, but on real device it doesn't work.

Comment: How do you create them so it works in the simulator?

Comment: Normally nothing needs to be done.
I guess your iPhone is unlocked. Just lock your iPhone and test the notification again. The push notification wont work if your iPhone is unlocked.

Answer (score 0):

iOS will decide where best to send any notification. **It will not just send to both devices.**

If iOS thinks it is best to display it on your phone, then it will notify there or vice versa.

iOS automatically makes that decision using facts such as you are wearing the Watch, because if you're not wearing the Watch, there's no point in sending a notification there.

Answer (score 0):

To test the receiving of notifications do the following:

1. Turn of the iPhone's screen.
2. Take on the Watch. It must be on your wrist.

The watch has the heart beat detector. Therefore, the watch will know if it is not wearn or not and only displays notifications if you wear it.